# ¿llenar un datatable en primefaces con el resultado de una consulta jpa nativa?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jpa

Mi pregunta es la siguiente tengo una consulta en mi gestor de base de datos la cual me arroja este resultado.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y un metodo en java que hace exactamente lo mismpo pero me muestra los datos de la siguiente forma. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

si hago un debug la lista se encuentra llena y me muestra los siguientes resultados.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero no se como mostrar ese vector en un datatable de primefaces que se me vea igual que la consulta el datatable lo estoy armando de esta forma pero no me vota ningun dato ni me genera error alguno, entonces como seria la estructura de mi datatable? gracias por su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que tendrías que utilizar el método `get()` donde le colocas el índice de la columna a mostrar según el número de columnas que tenga tu consulta nativa. Este base cero.

Comment: @Alexander Gil Tafur Lograste resolver el problema o todavia necesitas ayuda?